# Leaflet z-index above everything else

Tags: leaflet, z-index

I have a problem with leaflet : the control layers are always above everything else in my webpage. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

**My code creating the map**

```
var src_str = component.get('v.srcPath');
var grayscale = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGV2aXBsaW5lIiwiYSI6ImNpemZlZDZ2eDAwMDkycWw5OHdkdGNmYngifQ.2dPEOtBRw_koX7fFn2mwaQ', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.light'
});

var streets = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGV2aXBsaW5lIiwiYSI6ImNpemZlZDZ2eDAwMDkycWw5OHdkdGNmYngifQ.2dPEOtBRw_koX7fFn2mwaQ', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
});

var mymap;
try{
    mymap = L.map(
    'leafletmap', // map's <div> container ID
    {
        center: [47, 2.5],
        zoom: 6,
        layers: streets
    });

    var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
    markersLayer.addTo(mymap);

    var markerRed = new L.LayerGroup();
    markerRed.addTo(mymap);

    var markerOrange = new L.LayerGroup();
    markerOrange.addTo(mymap);

    var baseMaps = {
        "Région": grayscale,
        "Plan": streets
    };

    var overlayMaps = {};
    ol_mark_prefix = "<img style='height:20px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:10px;' src='" + src_str;    
    overlayMaps[ol_mark_prefix + "/MapCRI.png'/>"] = markerRed;
    overlayMaps[ol_mark_prefix + "/MapURG.png'/>"] = markerOrange;
    overlayMaps[ol_mark_prefix + "/MapGood.png'/>"] = markersLayer;

    L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlayMaps).addTo(mymap);

    // add the 'Smile.jpg' icon to the control layer
    var controlLayer = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-layers-toggle')[0];
    controlLayer.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src_str + '/Smile.jpg)';

    // because we need these later and can't have global variables in a component, I'll pass them via args !
    var markerArray = [markersLayer, markerRed, markerOrange];
    return markerArray;
}catch(e){
    this.logError(e);
}
```

**Here is my issue**

[image: Leaflet problem]
As you can see, both of the control layers are above the context menu of my page, the map being under this context menu. I want the control layers to have the same z-index as the map, so it sticks to it !

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution : [Leaflet layer control and legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/leaflet-layer-control-and-legend)

In `leaflet.css` : my `.leaflet-bottom z-index` was 1000. I changed it to 1. Might change it again later accordingly to new changes, but it fixed my problem for now.